# Eigen SVD with very large matrix

Tags: eigen, complex-numbers, svd, large-data

I need to calculate the SVD with a very large matrix of complex numbers.

The matrix dimensions are [260000][570].

By using the EIGEN libs I have defined:

```
MatrixXcf Lop_tmp
```

(even if MatrixXcd would be better).

However, I'm able to instantiate `Lop_tmp` but the SVD crashed (bad alloc) when invoked in this way:

```
Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXcf> svd(Lop_tmp.transpose(), Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
```

Supposing not to partitiong the algoritm, is there a way to compute the Eigen SVD with this `Lop_tmp`?

Thank you!

Comment: How much RAM do you have? The matrix alone takes 1.1GiB and `V` will require the same. Also, there will be a copy of `Lop_tmp.transpose()` inside your `svd` object.

Comment: Would computing an in-place QR decomposition of `Lop_tmp` be an option? (This would destroy Lop_tmp). And could you tell what you intend to do with `U` and `V` (just apply it to vectors, or inspect individual columns of it, or ...)?

Comment: @chtz, first of all, thanks! then, on my PC I've 16Gb of RAM. However,  on my server (128 Gb of RAM) is running properly. Now the point is that it took more than 2hours to solve the SVD on this huge matrix. On Matlab a few minuts give the same result... do you think it is due just to the multithreading embedded in matlab or some algorithmic differences?

Comment: @chtz, for what concerns the 2nd question. I need to reconstruct an image with an algo which works mainly on column multiplication among V and some sopporting vectors. I was also thinking to partition the problem (L_op) but I guess I'll lose some precision...